# How to align css class using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, margin

im trying to align several divs with each other, for some reason its not working. Im using a simple bootstrap template...My code snippet is below and My JS fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/sean3200/yU3TA/  Thanks!!

```
     I basically want my html to look like align such as:
     Album1: Name1
     Album2: Name2

    <div id="wellbox" class="well pull-right">
        <div><h3>Album Sales & Net worth</h3></div>
           <hr>
        <a href="#"><p id="album0">Album1:</p></a>
             <div><p id="albumdata0" class="album-class">Name1</p></div>

        <a  href="#"><p id="album1">Album2:</p></a>
             <div><p id="albumdata1" class="album-class"></p>Name2</div>

        <a  href="#"><p id="album2">Album3:</p></a>
             <div><p id="albumdata2"  class="album-class">Name3</p></div>

        <a  href="#"><p id="album3">Album3:</p></a>
             <div><p id="albumdata3" class="album-class"></p></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You could make the paragraphs inline, but do you really need to wrap each word in paragraphs? `<p>` in `<a>` is probably invalid HTML anyway

Comment: Yea @ One Trick Pony, i want my html document to automatically space my text within my <p> tag, so thats why each word is between the <p> and my <a>..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably restructure as so:

```
<div id="wellbox" class="well pull-right">
    <div><h3>Album Sales & Net worth</h3></div>
       <hr>
    <div class'albumContainer'>
        <a href="#"><p id="album0">Album1:</p></a>
        <div><p id="albumdata0" class="album-class">Name1</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then I would add the following style:

```
.albumContainer{
    clear: both;
}
.albumContainer a, .albumContainer div{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: @ KJ Prince this structures the styling jus the same as I had it, it dosent align the divs properly

Comment: @ KJ thanks, my divs were nested incorrectly.. problem fixed!